# Healtcheck on Websocket

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, events, websocket

I've looked through the documentation and haven't found that to be helpful.

I would like to know the best way to do a healthcheck on my websocket connection to geth (Yesterday, I found out that I did not receive the new event from a few days ago without any reason).

I have a solution but it is not likely the best practice approach.

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(networkUri));

setInterval(() => {
  console.log('Check WS status');
  let subscription;
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions')
      .on('data', function () {
        return resolve(true);
      })
      .on('error', function () {
        return reject(false);
      });
  })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('OK');
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('NOK');
      reconnect();
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // unsubscribes the subscription
      subscription.unsubscribe(function (error, success) {
        if (success)
          console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
      });
    })
}, 30000);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an open issue on that problem:

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1391

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1558

As it states (have not tested myself) there is end event which should detect closing

```
const wes3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws'));

wes3._provider.on('end', (eventObj) => {
    console.log('Disconnected: ');
    console.log(eventObj);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, unfortunately I never receive the 'end' event... I tried to turn off my internet connection and I did not receive anything